# How do I turn on Cycles Render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I was watching a UV wrapping tutorial and got stuck as the version of blender they use is different to mine.

I looked in the comments and people said that the way to fix it was to turn on cycles render. However, they do not specify where to find this. So I'm stuck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in the top of your screen:

[image]